# laravel Trouble link_to_action

Tags: php, laravel, warnings, confirm

I'm new to Laravel.

I want to show warning dialog before delete

```
{{link_to_action('RentsController@delete', 'delete',onclick="return confirm('are you sure delete this?')",array($l->id))}}
```

but it doesn't work for me, can somebody can explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you don't even pass a correct string, HTML attributes have to be the fourth argument and as array:

```
{{ link_to_action(
    'RentsController@delete',
    'delete',
    null,
    array(
        'onclick' => "return confirm('are you sure delete this?')",
        'id' => $l->id
    )
) }}
```